# Looping through csv file with inconsistent number of columns

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through a csv file with an inconsistent number of columns, then pair the data from column[0] to column[1], column[0] to column[2] and so on.

CSV example:

```
ID, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4
1, alfred, enrique, mark
2, robert, james
3, mike, jack, todd, buddy
```

Expected output written to .txt file:

```
1 + alfred
1 + enrique
1 + mark
2 + robert 
2 + james
3 + mike
3 + jack
3 + todd
3 + buddy
```

The first solution that comes to mind is to fill all of the Values that don't have any text with "abc" in excel and then when I'm doing the addition for the expected output, remove any rows with "abc" in them before writing to the .txt file, but I don't think that's the best approach...

Comment: Have you bothered to read the documentation for the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module? There are several options for dealing with row with missing values. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a place to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard library csv file reader:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Specifically it says:

> If a row has more fields than fieldnames, the remaining data is put in a list and stored with the fieldname specified by restkey (which defaults to None). If a non-blank row has fewer fields than fieldnames, the missing values are filled-in with the value of restval (which defaults to None).

Then when you loop over the columns, skip if the value is None.

Comment: That's if you use `DictReader`.  Regular `csv.reader` will just give you a list of varying size as you iterate rows.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for the lack of context I provided in my post. I had already been using the csv file reader. I was looking for an eloquent way to generate some strings if a  value existed. I ended up using if statements to check if the strings existed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pandas` for this. It solves the empty column values automatically by assigning `NaN` values:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv')
df = df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index(level=0, name='value').reset_index(drop=True) # stack the columns
df.to_csv('filename.txt', index=False, header=False, sep='+') # save as csv (txt) file with + as delimiter to achieve the desired output
```

Answer (score 0):

`csv.reader` handles differing rows fine.  I leave it to you to process the lines...

```py
import csv

with open('input.csv',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f,skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in r:
        print(row)
```

```
['ID', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4']
['1', 'alfred', 'enrique', 'mark']
['2', 'robert', 'james']
['3', 'mike', 'jack', 'todd', 'buddy']
```